# cakephp + cache + formhelper inside <cake:nocache></cake:nocache> = error

Tags: cakephp, forms, caching, helper

in all my views i have a login/register (cake)form.

my question: 
can i use the file cache engine with `<cake:nocache>form</ cake:nocache>`

1.) open url "www.domain.com/home"
2.) cachefile generated
3.) look perfect
4.) refresh (f5)
5.) error (when debug=1):

```
Parse error: parse error in C:\xampp\htdocs\cake_1.2.3.8166\app\tmp\cache\view \cake_1_2_3_8166_home.php on line 752
```

cachefile -> line 752 -> `</html>`

cakephp: 1.2.3.8166
example:

```
<cake:nocache>
<?
$user = $session->read("user");
if(!$user){ //$user true or false
    echo "login:";
    echo $form->create('AdminUser', array('action' =>'login_load'));
    echo $form->input('email',array('label'=>false));
    echo $form->input('password',array('label'=>false));
    echo $form->submit('Login', array('id'=>'login'));
    echo $form->end();
}else{
    echo "hello user!";
}?>
</cake:nocache>
```

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're asking. Please provide additional detail about what you'd like Cake to do that it isn't doing.

Comment: That sounds like you're missing a closing tag or statement terminator somewhere in your file.

Comment: cakephp build the wrong code when i use formhelper inside 'nocache'

Comment: That seems to be a bug. The best course of action would be to make a test case and report it.

Comment: partial solution. but the central question still undissolved. after refresh i lost the data between <cake:nocache>

Answer (score 1):

it's a cakephp bug. [cake google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/3ad96f4680bf0211/5037e35ef4ff8273)

Answer (score 0):

The dev state at https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/6034 CakePHP does not support using the form helper from within  tags at this time.